# memory leak reading video frames to numpy array using ffmpeg as a python subprocess

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg, memory-leaks, subprocess

I can stream videos frame by frame to an OpenGL Texture2D OK in python (pi3d module, example in pi3d_demos/VideoWalk.py) but I've noticed that it gradually leaks memory. Below is a stripped down version of the code that shows the problem.

Can anyone see where I'm leaking? The memory seems to be recovered when python stops. I've tried explicitly setting things to `None` or calling the garbage collector manually.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import json

def get_dimensions(video_path):
    probe_cmd = f'ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height,avg_frame_rate -of json "{video_path}"'
    probe_result = subprocess.check_output(probe_cmd, shell=True, text=True)
    video_info_list = [vinfo for vinfo in json.loads(probe_result)['streams'] if 'width' in vinfo]
    if len(video_info_list) > 0:
        video_info = video_info_list[0] # use first if more than one!
        return(video_info['width'], video_info['height'])
    else:
        return None

class VideoStreamer:
    def __init__(self, video_path):
        self.flag = False # use to signal new texture
        self.kill_thread = False
        self.command = [ 'ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, '-f', 'image2pipe',
                        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']
        dimensions = get_dimensions(video_path)
        if dimensions is not None:
            (self.W, self.H) = dimensions
            self.P = 3
            self.image = np.zeros((self.H, self.W, self.P), dtype='uint8')
            self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_thread)
            self.t.start()
        else: # couldn't get dimensions for some reason - assume not able to read video
            self.W = 240
            self.H = 180
            self.P = 3
            self.image = np.zeros((self.H, self.W, self.P), dtype='uint8')
            self.t = None

    def pipe_thread(self):
        pipe = None
        while not self.kill_thread:
            st_tm = time.time()
            if pipe is None:
                pipe = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
            self.image = np.frombuffer(pipe.stdout.read(self.H * self.W * self.P), dtype='uint8') # overwrite array
            pipe.stdout.flush() # presumably nothing else has arrived since read()
            pipe.stderr.flush() # ffmpeg sends commentary to stderr
            if len(self.image) < self.H * self.W * self.P: # end of video, reload
                pipe.terminate()
                pipe = None
            else:
                self.image.shape = (self.H, self.W, self.P)
                self.flag = True
            step = time.time() - st_tm
            time.sleep(max(0.04 - step, 0.0)) # adding fps info to ffmpeg doesn't seem to have any effect
        if pipe is not None:
            pipe.terminate()
            pipe = None

    def kill(self):
        self.kill_thread = True
        if self.t is not None:
            self.t.join()

vs = None
try:
    while True:
        for (path, _, videos) in os.walk("/home/patrick/Pictures/videos"):
            for video in videos:
                print(video)
                os.system("free") # shows gradually declining memory available
                vs = VideoStreamer(os.path.join(path, video))
                for i in range(500):
                    tries = 0
                    while not vs.flag and tries < 5:
                        time.sleep(0.001)
                        tries += 1
                    # at this point vs.image is a numpy array HxWxP bytes
                    vs.flag = False
                vs.kill()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if vs is not None:
        vs.kill()


os.system("free")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there were two factors that confused me. The first was a bug in `pcmanfm` used by Wayland on bookworm on the Raspberry Pi (at least) that was hanging onto image data.

The second was due to the timing of releasing stream handles and this latter can be fixed by using a context manager (i.e. `with Popen(...stdout=PIPE) as pipe:` as probably should always be done but isn't often shown explicitly for `subprocess.Popen`. So as above but the threaded part:

```py
    def pipe_thread(self):
        while not self.kill_thread:
            with subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1) as pipe:
                while pipe.poll() is None and not self.kill_thread:
                    st_tm = time.time()
                    self.flag = False
                    self.image = np.frombuffer(pipe.stdout.read(self.H * self.W * self.P), dtype='uint8') # overwrite array
                    self.image.shape = (self.H, self.W, self.P)
                    self.flag = True
                    step = time.time() - st_tm
                    time.sleep(max(0.04 - step, 0.0)) # adding fps info to ffmpeg doesn't seem to have any effect
```